# How do I enable .php extensions on my pages?

Tags: php, .htaccess, iis, web-config

I am currently making a series of pages but I am having a problem.
I downloaded a base for this project which included the .htaccess and web.config files.
When I navigate to the url of my site it automatically redirects to http://example.com/index which is correct, i want it to do that but I would like it to display http://example.com/index.php instead. (the .php extension)
I am running on an IIS 7 web server on a Windows VPS 2008 VPS with Helicon ape installed along with url rewrite, iis recommended configuration and php.

Answer (score 0):

You just need home.php in your DirectoryIndex to make it works. Remember that this is using in .htaccess file of your root project:
DirectoryIndex home.php

Comment: That doesn't work, when I put that in .htaccess and then visit the url - http://example.com/index.php it just redirects me to http://example.com/index

Comment: I'm assuming you have it configured to allow .htaccess files. If it isn't, you'll have to modify the setting in configuration file (httpd.conf)



`1.Create a .htaccess file in your web root.


2.Add the line...




DirectoryIndex index.php`

Comment: I've found out that if I remove this `<rule name="Imported Rule 2-2">
                    <match url="^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)(|/)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?url={R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
                </rule>` from the web.config it sends the website to http://example.com/404 does this help finding a solution to allowing the extension .php?

Comment: I'v also found out that if I remove (|/)$ from this code snippet: `<match url="^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)(|/)$"` it allows you to put example.com/index.php and it sends you to it but when you visit example.com it doesn't display the  /index automatically. I think it is something to do with the match url.